# Strange Travel Path in Quick Smoke Simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Every time I run a quick smoke simulation regardless whether it is in a new or existing file it creates this strange travel path where it goes off to the side and looks like it gets cut of on the top.

Any suggestions on what I can do in the settings to stop this from happening?

thanks.

[image: Quick Smoke Simulation]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may just need to up the resolution divisions. If not, please include the .blend file as it is hard to figure out the problem without it.